# XNA and multitouch

Tags: xna

I use XNA to develop small 2D games. The user should have the ability to interact with the game by using the mutli touch gestures in Windows 7. I want the same multi touch functionality in XNA as WPF provides. Are there any frameworks or built-in features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you probably already know, the XNA touch API does not work on Windows, only on Windows Phone.

[This blog post explains why](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/09/09/touch-input-on-windows-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) and also lists some methods for getting touch input working.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this code sample about touch-based textures for WP7, it can be useful for what you want.

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/gestures

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to say that I develop game for Windows, not for WP7.