# Develop multi-touch games for Windows

Tags: xna

I would like to develop a 2D multi-touch game for windows. I've asked here([XNA and multitouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355841/xna-and-multitouch)) how to use multi-touch in XNA. I get the answer that is not directly possible. There are wrappers for XNA which I could use, but this is a bit difficult. So there are no built-in features for XNA.

The other option is WPF. WPF provides a multi-touch API. Very easy to use. There are also frameworks for physics and so forth.

My Problem is now to choose between XNA and WPF. WPF is easy an cool, but for game development difficult. With XNA is it easy to develop games for Windows. Problem is that there are not multi-touch frameworks for XNA.

As I above said, I would like to develop a multi-touch game. Are there any other possibilities or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be of any use?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/XnaInWPF.aspx

XNA can be integrated into WPF as far as I'm aware, so I would assume (I haven't tried it) that all you would need to do is to create some sort of interface from the multi-touch input to the XNA input classes.

Also this link is basically what you're trying to do, I believe:

http://xna-uk.net/blogs/randomchaos/archive/2010/02/10/xna-and-windows-7-multi-touch.aspx